Method to compare two latency measurement groups
I have two measurement (or rather two or more sets of measurements) of server software (DNS).
The measurement results does not have normal distribution, they are very skewed towards 0-1 milisecond range.
As an example:

total is 41178744
the latencies look like this:

    37     ▽ latency: (2001) [24673509, 12560724, 360898, 248331, 173744, 137900, 116894, 102247, 84900, 76741, 76066, 62945, 56794, 53765, 51767, 51180, 49078, 48807, 48590, 48472, 47094, 45483, 43727, 40700, 38913, 37…, …]
    38         [0]: 24673509
    39         [1]: 12560724
    40         [2]: 360898
    41         [3]: 248331
    42         [4]: 173744
    43         [5]: 137900
    44         [6]: 116894
    45         [7]: 102247
    46         [8]: 84900
    47         [9]: 76741
    48         [10]: 76066
    49         [11]: 62945
    50         [12]: 56794
    51         [13]: 53765
    52         [14]: 51767
    53         [15]: 51180
    54         [16]: 49078
    55         [17]: 48807
    56         [18]: 48590
    57         [19]: 48472
    58         [20]: 47094
    [...]

There's around 2001 buckets.
The resulting data looks like this:

Beware that the graph is "turned-down" and on logarithmic scale, see https://blog.apnic.net/2017/11/24/dns-performance-metrics-logarithmic-percentile-histogram/ for explanation.
I can pretty much tell by eye that all the measurements of main branch are similar and all the measurements of each-qpcache-heavy branch are not, but I am pretty much at loss how to test the differences using the statistical method.
I'm converting the data from the latencies back to full dataset in python with following code:
def gen_data_from_json(json):
    sum = json['stats_sum']
    data = []
    ms = 1
    for resps in sum['latency']:
        for x in range(resps):
            data.append(ms)
        ms += 1
    return data

I've already tries Kolmogorov–Smirnov test and failed (the p-value is always 0.0 even between main1 and main2 groups).
I've tried normalizing the data using Boxcox and then using one-way ANOVA (and two-way t-test), but again the p-value is just 0.0.
The aforementioned article suggests:
Monitoring/alerting based on logarithmic percentile histogram

As noted, the shape of these graphs is very robust — temporary outliers barely show up for example. Only real changes in network or server conditions make the graph move. This makes these percentiles exceptionally suitable for monitoring. Setting limits on ‘1%’ and ‘0.1%’ slowest performance is both sensitive and specific: it detects all real problems, and everything it detects is a real problem.

So, perhaps I could just take this route, pick the slowest 1% from each sets and then work with these.
As an example, if I take just the last value in the results field (that's queries not answered under < 2000 ms):
>>> print(main_per)
[284243, 292413, 271626, 294025, 285524]
>>> print(each_per)
[910587, 898288, 894027, 892618, 879973]
>>> stats.shapiro(main_per)
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.9037228358106117, pvalue=0.4308025315693231)
>>> stats.shapiro(each_per)
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.9700229533553387, pvalue=0.8754009192891016)
>>> stats.f_oneway(main_per, each_per)
F_onewayResult(statistic=9280.58639361942, pvalue=1.505113310148663e-13)

Alternatively, this is something I can probably do on all the millisecond buckets, but I am not sure if that's needed.
But I am not a statistician, and there might be some more clever way how to work with such skewed data.
Edit: I should probably add that if we can get away by comparing just two runs for each branch it would save us some time on AWS.  So, if this could be made into multistep, it would be also helpful.
